# Hide div when clicked outside without using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I hide a `<div>` when I click outside it using `onblur`? I tried with the code below, but when I click the checkbox it disappears, and when I click outside of it, it won’t disappear.

I then tried using `window` or `document` object which works, but is not supported by the platform that I’m currently using.

Is this otherwise possible using JavaScript and/or CSS?

```js
var expanded = false;

function showshow() {
  var show = document.getElementById("show");

  if (!expanded) {
    show.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    show.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}

function hideshow() {
  var show = document.getElementById("show");

  if (expanded) {
    show.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}
```

```css
#show {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#show label {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#show label:hover {
  background-color: #eff1f4;
}
```

```html
<form id="input-form">
  <button type="button" onclick="showshow()">Select an option</button>

  <div id="show" tabindex="1" onblur="hideshow()">
    <label for="OptionA">
<input type="checkbox" id="OptionA" value="Option A" />Option A</label>
    <label for="OptionB">
<input type="checkbox" id="OptionB" value="Option B" />Option B</label>
    <label for="OptionC">
<input type="checkbox" id="OptionC" value="Option C" />Option ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What platform are you using that doesn’t support `addEventListener`? [98.8% of browsers used globally support it](https://caniuse.com/#search=addEventListener)

Comment: sorry what i'm trying to say is i can't use document and window object it's because i'm using lightning

Answer (score 0):

if you can't use `addEventListener` on your platform maybe you can try `attachEvent` that will do the job on old platform.
Exemple:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {                // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
  document.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
} else if (document.attachEvent) {              // For IE 8 and earlier versions
  document.attachEvent("onclick", myFunction);
}
```

Best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call the `hideshow` function when the `click` event is fired on the document's body, then check if the event's target is `document.body`:

```js
var expanded = false;

function showshow(event) {
  var show = document.getElementById("show");
  if (!expanded) {
    show.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    show.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;       
  }   
}
function hideshow(event) {
  var show = document.getElementById("show");
  var elem = event.target;
  
  // Check if the event's target is the document's body
  if(elem && elem.id == "main") {
    show.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;       
  }   
}
document.body.onclick = hideshow;
```

```css
html,
body,
#main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#show {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}

#show label {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#show label:hover {
  background-color: #eff1f4;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <button type="button" id="toggle-modal" onclick="showshow(event)">Select an option</button>     
  <div id="show" tabindex="1" onblur="hideshow(event)"> 
    <label for="OptionA">
      <input type="checkbox" id="OptionA" value="Option A" />
      Option A
    </label>
    <label for="OptionB">
      <input type="checkbox" id="OptionB" value="Option B" />Option B
    </label>
    <label for="OptionC">
      <input type="checkbox" id="OptionC" value="Option C" />Option ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    </label>
   </div> 
</main>
```